# changing a Percentage value form a minus to a positive

Tags: magento-1.9, price

I am using this code to work out how much much someone is saving on a sale product

```
<?php
   // Display Percentage
   $totalPercent = (($_finalPrice / $_regularPrice*1.2 ) *100) - 100;

   echo "<div class='savings'>";
   echo "Saving you: ".round($totalPercent)."%";
   echo "</div>";
?>
```

It is giving me back the correct discount amount but it is displaying as negative
EG. when the customer save 44% is says `Saving you: -44%`
So the question is how can I convert the negative number to a positive?

Thank you

Comment: Use the PHP function `abs()`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about algebra not Magento.

Comment: just put it in here as i am using it in magento

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the total percent like this:

```
$totalPercent = 100 - (($_finalPrice / $_regularPrice*1.2 ) *100);
```